# Trying to pull data using importxml

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to pull from a website that has a line of text from a `<code>` line using importxml. It didn't work but here's what I tried:

`=importxml("https://www.apqc.org/what-we-do/benchmarking/open-standards-benchmarking/measures/employee-turnover-rate", "//div[@class='c-compute-measure__fx-include']")`

Here is the section I'm pulling from:

[image]

Comment: It seems your existing formula works on my end as seen [on my testing](https://imgur.com/a/8vHBMtA). Are you getting any errors? Or What do you see on your end?

Answer (score -1):

When I view the source the data being put into that `div` tag is dynamically being calculated and isn't static.  I' don't think `importxml` works for data like that.